# how to properly write url in httpBackend service in unit tests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, https, httpbackend

I want to mock `$httpBackend.whenGet` request.

I can write full url as string, but i can not uderstend with last part where i define queryExpression: `"('120' != 1 AND '106' != 5)"`

Example of request from console that working:

```
http://localhost:9002/api/application/datapage?dataPageType=application.group.datapage.GroupDataPageQuery&pageSize=-1&propertySelection=groupName,groupId&queryExpression=(%27120%27+!%3D+1+AND+%27106%27+!%3D+5)&startIndex=0
```

if i past this as string in `$httpBackend.whenGET( '/api/application/datapage?dataPageType=application.group.datapage.GroupDataPageQuery&pageSize=-1&propertySelection=groupName,groupId&queryExpression=(%27120%27+!%3D+1+AND+%27106%27+!%3D+5)&startIndex=0' )`,

i have Unexpected Error in my unit tests

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET /api/application/datapage?dataPageType=application.group.datapage.GroupDataPageQuery&pageSize=-1&propertySelection=groupName,groupId&queryExpression=('120'+!%3D+1+AND+'106'+!%3D+5)&startIndex=0
```

I define that proplem with wrong format of `queryExpression`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First case that it is not so urgent to mock full url for request, i can use RegExp in `$httpBackend.whenGet` service for match parameters without query.

Second is what i asked and resolution is simple, using `\` escape character.

So, the result is:

```
/api/application/datapage?dataPageType=application.group.datapage.GroupDataPageQuery&pageSize=-1&propertySelection=groupName,groupId&queryExpression=(\'120\'+!%3D+1+AND+\'106\'+!%3D+5)&startIndex=0
```